# UFW Delete 1 (or more) Rule(s) (silently)?

Tags: ufw, delete

Is there a way to make `Ubuntu Fire Wall` delete a rule without asking if I really want to delete it?

Just like you "pre-yes" `apt install [package]` by `-y`.

I want to be able to read out only the `DENY IN` rules, sort them numerically by IP, delete those specific existing rules and then reapply them in the sorted order.

I have spent a long time to create my script (more less finised), to realise that I can't delete rules without saying: `Yes, I really want to delete it.`

I am aware, that I could read out all of my rules (not only DENY IN ones), and reset UFW and then reapply all of them, but I don't want to reset the firewall. The other rules never change, so I want to leave them alone.

Even if I first do `sudo -i`, UFW will still ask that question.

So, are any of you aware of a way to make UFW delete a rule without asking if I really want to delete it?

I also can't find an option like that on the man page.

Comment: Check here https://superuser.com/q/1564138/275918

Comment: That is Great.. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris I finally had time to try it, and it worked perfectly.. Thanks